# Analytic continuation of $a^{q}$

Tags: multivalued-functions

Although I have completed a Bachelor of Science degree,
I have never learnt complex analysis in college.

Let $F(a) = a^{q}$ with $q$ non integer.
It is known that as $a$ passes over the negative 
real axis, we need to consider the situation
in which $F(a)$ is a multi-valued function.

Thus $(e^{0})^{q}$ is differrent from $(e^{2 \pi i})^{q}$.

Now, is it possible that we calculate $F(a)$ using power series
expansion at $a = a_{0}$ with $a_{0}$ very close to 
and below the negative real axis ?

For instance, 
the power series of $F(a)$ at $a = a_{0}$ is
\[
F(a) = \sum_{n \geq 0} F^{(n)}(a_{0})/n! (a - a_{0})^{n}.
\]
Now,
\[
F^{0}(a_{0}) = a_{0}^{q},
\ldots , F^{(n)}(a_{1}) = q(q - 1)\cdots (q + n - 1)(a_{0})^{q - n},
\]
and so the power series of $F(a)$ ought to be valid
for $|a - a_{0}| < |a_{0}|$.

That way, could we go over the negative real axis in $a$
claiming that the power series assigns a unique extension
to $a^{q}$?

This may be rather a basic question, but I always doubt
when multi-valued functions play the role of multi-valuedness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, you can get multivaluedness on the positive real axis as well. Consider a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(a)^2 = a$ for any $a > 0$. We want to say this is _the_ square root function, but there are actually two choices for it: we can have $f(1) = 1$ or $f(1) = -1$. Which is "better"?

Comment: I choose $-\pi \leq \arg z < \pi$ as the principal value of $\log z$, by the way.